# Error querying database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hey i can connect to my database but i can't write into table with php.i wrote this code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO propety_1 (first_name, last_name,email, radio, desc)".
"VALUES ('$name', '$last', '$to', '$fang_rad', '$desc')";

  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error querying database.');



mysqli_close($dbc)
or die('Error ');
```

The page show up 'Error querying database; and nothing happened.

Comment: `mysqli_error($dbc)` will show you what the problem is with the query. I suspect it's that `property` is spelled wrong.

Comment: i wrote it wrong when i created the table. mysqli_error($dbc) nothing show me.

Comment: Are you echoing out the error? Replace `die('Error querying database.')` with `die(mysqli_error($dbc))`.

Comment: Does your Database user has accesss to INSERT commands?

Comment: Yes it does.mysqli_error shows me : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('a', 'adasdsa', 'ali.fifamania@gmail.com', 'Yes', 'sdas')' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

desc is a reserved word, put it in backticks  or use a different name.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO propety_1 (first_name, last_name,email, radio, `desc`)".
"VALUES ('$name', '$last', '$to', '$fang_rad', '$desc')";
```